# Setting a Wildcard Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, wildcard

Below is my code. I need the `*` to be a wildcard so any number can be in its place. Any ideas?

```
$('body').on('click', '.custom_295_*-row', function(){
  var href = "https://randomsite.co.uk/forms/mortgage-club-proc-fees";
  popup(href, '', 600, 600);
})
```

Comment: There's no wildcard selector in jQuery. You could potentially use the 'attribute starts with' and 'attribute ends with' selectors, but this will be easily broken if you have multiple classes on the element. The best solution would be to put the same class on every element and not worry about the wildcard at all. Especially given that the value in the wildcard has no bearing whatsoever on the logic in the event handler.

Comment: You could use `'[class^=custom_295_][class$=-row]'`. But, you're probably better off adding the same class to every element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Hi Guys, Unfortunately i cant the rows are generated from a CRM system. How can i assign a class to all the rows. I have tried [class^=custom_295_][class$=-row] before and it doesnt work.

Comment: `How can i assign a class to all the rows` amend the template your CRM uses. Alternatively you could select the elements based on their ancestors, but we can't help with that without seeing the HTML

Comment: @Moe, can you provide a markup sample? this would help in finding an actual solution.

Answer (score -1):

I'd add the click handlers to the object directly:

```
$("*[class^=custom_295_][class$=-row]").on('click', e => { 
    console.log(e);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/an2w81dv/

if you dont want that you could check the element class in the handler like so:

```
$("body").on("click", (e) => {
    console.log("now check the class with a RE", e.target.className);
    if (e.target.className.match(/^custom_295_(.*)-row$/)) {
        console.log("now do something..");
    }
})
```

Comment: `I have tried [class^=custom_295_][class$=-row] before and it doesnt work`

Comment: 1) I am not the OP. 2) this only works if the `custom_295_*-row` class is the **only** one on the element. Clearly it's not for the OP as it doesn't work. 3) your second example seems to be half an answer. How exactly do you filter the `className` to match the value you're looking for?

Comment: added a jsfiddle to show that it does work and showed how you would use a RE to test the className

Comment: and yes, the first example only works when the class is the only one on the element. otherwise of course, *= could be used.